# javascript can't delete object key when not in quotes

Tags: javascript, json

I've come across an issue while trying to remove keys from a json object:

```
var doc = this.data;
  Object.keys(doc).forEach(function(key) {
      if (isPropertyEmpty(doc[key])){
        delete doc[key];
      };
  });
```

The following loop passes over a JSON object which is formatted like this:

```
{ notes: [],
 isHostessGift: false,
  playbook: {},
  location: {},
  wine: { ingredient: false, pairing: false },
  coupons: [],
  ingredients: [{ item: 'e' }],
  categories: { dishType: ["Beverage"], mainIngredient: ["e"] },
  directions: [{ step: 'e' }],
  headline: 'jnj' }
```

It should remove the keys with empty arrays: coupons and notes

For some reason it isn't, but when I hard-coded the data, adding quotes around the keys:

```
{ "notes": [],
isHostessGift: false,
  playbook: {},
  location: {},
  wine: { ingredient: false, pairing: false },
  "coupons": [],
  ingredients: [{ item: 'e' }],
  categories: { dishType: ["Beverage"], mainIngredient: ["e"] },
  directions: [{ step: 'e' }],
  headline: 'jnj' }
```

They are removed. Is there any reason for the difference in functionality?

```
function isPropertyEmpty(obj) {

for (var key in obj) {
    if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)){
       if(typeof obj === 'function') return false;
       if (obj == null)       return true;
       if (obj.length === 0)  return true;
       if(_.isEmpty(obj))     return true; 
       if (obj.length > 0)    return false;
    };
    return false;
}


 }
```

Comment: quotes or no quotes should makes zero difference in an object. FYI: An object is not JSON. What is `isPropertyEmpty`?

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior in a complete example (optionally hosted on http://jsfiddle.net or similar)? As far as I can tell, there is no explanation based on the information you've given, so you should provide a complete example that is guaranteed to include the relevant problematic code.

Comment: seems works fine http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/qgshnr6e/, maybe problem with isPropertyEmpty

Comment: The error is occurring in node, maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: How is `this.data` created? If it's a Mongoose model instance or something like that the properties don't exist directly on the object

Comment: Simple debug shows it has nothing to do with quotes: `console.log(isPropertyEmpty([]));`

Comment: yes, I needed to change var doc = this.data to var doc = this.data.toObject().

Answer (score 2):

As I said before problem in `isPropertyEmpty`, for empty arrays it returns `undefined`, I've rewritten it and seems works fine

```js
var doc = { 
    "notes": [],
 isHostessGift: false,
    playbook: {},
    location: {},
    wine: { ingredient: false, pairing: false },
    "coupons": [],
    ingredients: [{ item: 'e' }],
    categories: { dishType: ["Beverage"], mainIngredient: ["e"] },
    directions: [{ step: 'e' }],
    headline: 'jnj'
};

Object.keys(doc).forEach(function(key) {
    if (isPropertyEmpty(doc[key])) {
        delete doc[key];
    };
});


function isPropertyEmpty(obj) {
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

    if (obj === null || obj.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    
    if (typeof obj === 'function' || typeof obj === 'boolean') {
        return false;
    }

    if (obj.length > 0) {
        return false;
    }
    
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}


console.log(doc);
```